# Search from a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have a workbook with data in several sheets (One by brand). I need to do a search from other workbook and get all the results.

This code works but only if searching in the same workbook.

Did someone knows how I can modify my code to do it?

```
Sub Search_With_Multiple_Results()

Dim Results As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Found
Dim FirstAddress
Dim r

r = 5

 For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set Found = Nothing
    With Sheet.UsedRange
        Set Found = .Cells.Find(What:="Value searched", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart,  SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Found.Address
            Do
                If Results = vbNullString Then
                    r = r + 1: Results = "Worksheet(" & Sheet.Index & ").Range(" & Chr(34) & 
Found.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                    Cells(r, 7).Value = Results
                Else
                    Results = Results & "|" & "Worksheet(" & Sheet.Index & ").Range(" & Chr(34) &  Found.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                        r = r + 1: Results = "Worksheet(" & Sheet.Index & ").Range(" & Chr(34) & 
Found.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                        Cells(r, 7).Value = Results
                End If
                Set Found = .FindNext(Found)
            Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
Next
    If FirstAddress = Empty Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

to

```
For Each Sheet In Workbooks("All Brands.xlsx").Worksheets
```